# Automated Test Management: Running, Saving Results, Querying, etc

Tags: automated-testing, test-management

The team I am currently working with has a very large application to test (several custom programs, running in a distributed environment), and has built up a very large set of automated test cases for regression and feature testing. These tests are large and there are a lot, so full test runs are dispatched across many machines, the results gathered, and then imported into a custom web app.

There are some very nice tools out there for writing the automated tests, but there doesn't seem to be much for managing a "automated testing workplace". We ended up writing custom applications to do all of the following:

- Schedule tests to run on one of several machines
- Gather results, import into database
- Web application for result viewing and querying

  - Results per run/software version/test machine/etc
- Integration with external bug tracker for tracing failures to tests
- Nice to have: Smart analysis of results

  - "This test started failing/passing"
  - "This test is unreliable/intermittent"
  - etc

Does anyone know of anything off the shelf that handles all of the above? Most of what I have found before is very focused on manual testing, which we don't do much of.

Comment: At my company we have also created custom solutions for much of this.  I would love to see a response from someone with some tools that have "everything" you would need, but I don't know of any.  It seems like a pretty big gap in the industry if you ask me.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding correctly you could use a [Continuous Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) tool like:

- [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/)

> Jenkins is an award-winning application that monitors executions of repeated jobs, such as building a software project or jobs run by cron.

- [Team City](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)

> TeamCity is a user-friendly continuous integration (CI) server for professional developers and build engineers, like ourselves. It is trivial to setup, manage and use. It scales perfectly for a company or a team of any size.

Both have numerous features, which you can browse via their respective websites. We are currently using Jenkins to run our automated tests (smoke, regression and unit tests). It does a nice job of reporting and is customizable so that you can a variety of plugins (which are available via the Jenkins site).

We push tests to different machines and test results for the tests are reported within Jenkins.

Comment: We currently use Jenkins for running builds and unit tests, but not for larger system tests. I don't feel like the reporting in Jenkins is useful enough for managing 1000's of granular test results in a queryable way.

Comment: As an example, we have 1000's of long running system tests. I would want to kick those off periodically, but also be able to kick off each test manually. In Jenkins, every test would have to be a separate task so that I can dispatch granularly... but if I then want to run all tests with a tag, then what? Click each task to dispatch it?

Comment: Good point Chris. I agree with downside of Jenkins. To combat that - we have tests broken into their individual state and then have them packaged into suites so that you can either run them separately or run them as a suite.